# Using Java 8 forEach to add views to tablerow

Tags: java, android, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getContext());
List<File> threeFiles = listOfFiles.subList(i, i+2);
threeFiles.forEach(action ->  tableRow.addView(new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(action.getAbsolutePath()))));
```

On the last line, it says addView(android.view.View) in ViewGroup cannot be applied to (void).
How do I use Java 8 ForEach to addViews with file sources to a table row? I'm trying to make more use of Java 8 Streams to make my code more concise

Comment: Show the original error text from log

Comment: It is not a runtime error, it is an IDE highlight error.

Comment: FWIW, the `Iterable.forEach` method is **not** related to Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is by adding `setBackground` at the end makes the line returns void since `setBackground` returns void, you may need to spit the line like this :

```
threeFiles.forEach(action -> {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setBackground(Drawable.createFromPath(action.getAbsolutePath());
            tableRow.addView(imageView);
        });
```